# Search for TcmId without opening item directly

Tags: 2013-sp1, 2011-sp1, search

Apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't find a matching question so thought I'd ask anyway.

Is there a way of preventing the Tridion CME from opening an item when you search for a tcmId in the CME search?

Our client is using tcmIds heavily for locating components which they would like to add to pages etc and the issue they have is that the CME is opening the component in a new tab, rather than just returning the item within the CME list view. This means that they have to then look for the component's location in the Content Manager, browse for the folder and then add the component that way.

Would it need to be a GUI extension to prevent the new window from being opened and to allow the search to actually search in the usual way?

This is a question for both Tridion 2011 and Tridion 2013.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, however... You can make make Tridion search on Solr's Id field for a specific Id by using the query `Id:tcm\:x-yyyy` (where `x` is the publication ID and `yyyy` is the component Id of course). Note the escaping of the second `:`.

This works in the main Content Manager Explorer, for example...

[image: Id search in CME]

...and also in the Insert Component Presentation dialogue (which sounds like your main use case).

[image: Id search in Insert Component Presentation]

Note that my page is actually not in Publication 1 here, but the search results are showing me the component in the correct context anyway. Sometimes that doesn't seem to work, throwing an error regarding an incorrect Publication context when you try to select a Component Template to use. The good news is that with a slight modification to use a wildcard for the publication ID (i.e `Id:tcm\:*-yyyy`) it behaves much better...

[image]

... it also has a rather nice effect in the main CME window where it will show you the parent component and it's localised versions!

[image: Wildcard Id search in CME]

Comment: Thanks @David, this is probably the most sensible solution I've seen and it isn't too complicated to explain to content editors (essentially, the "Id:tcm\:*-" remains the same each time and just the item id is changed). It also gives the nice side effect of the localised versions too which is definitely a bonus!

Answer (score 3):

If there is a logical naming/grouping conventions or common tagging params on the components, you can create virtual folders. Virtual folders can be created for search query and results will be shown in the folder for the search query and the users can select components from the same. For e.g. if you have groupings/tagging like "product" or "electronics" etc. you can create a virtual folder with `*product*` as the search query and the results will be shown in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual folders is one approach (as Vipin highlighted above).

A different approach would be to use the [Item Selector Custom URL eXtension](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/itemselector.aspx) when creating the Tridion items. Following is a list of items that you can filter using ItemSelector.

- Publication = 1
- Folder = 2
- StructureGroup = 4
- Schema = 8
- Component = 16
- ComponentTemplate = 32
- Page = 64
- PageTemplate = 128
- TargetGroup = 256
- Category = 512
- Keyword = 1024
- TemplateBuildingBlock = 2048
- VirtualFolder = 8192

Offcourse, you would need to validate all of your use cases!